# XPath PHP - check if class exists in a parent class

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have this kind of HTML file:

```
<div class="find-this">I do not need this</div>

<div class="content ">
    <div class="find-this">
          <span class="yellowcard"></span>
          <span class="name">Cristiano Ronaldo</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=" content">
    <div class="find-this">
        <span class="redcard"></span>
        <span class="name">Lionel Messi</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far, I get the `find-this` class that are in `content` parent class.

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class,'content')]//div[@class='find-this']");
foreach ($nodes as $key => $node) {
        echo "Player ". $key .": " . $node->nodeValue;
    }
```

Result:

```
Player0: Cristiano Ronaldo
Player1: Lionel Messi
```

How I can find out which `find-this` class is parent of `<span class="yellowcard">` and which one is parent of `<span class="redcard">`?
Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the `find-this` `div` which is a parent of `<span class="yellowcard">` and the `div` which is parent of `<span class="redcard">` use the XPaths shown below:

```
$yellow_nodes = $xpath->query("//span[@class='yellowcard']/parent::div[@class='find-this']");
$red_nodes = $xpath->query("//span[@class='redcard']/parent::div[@class='find-this']");
```